# Powershell xml accessing key pair value

Tags: xml, powershell, plist

I have this sample xml file in the following format. How do I access the value for a key directly using Powershell?

Eg: $xml.array.dict.key.name -> bob, kate, john

```
$xml = @'
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>name</key>
        <string>bob</string>
        <key>age</key>
        <string>35</string>
        <key>gender</key>
        <string>male</string>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>name</key>
        <string>kate</string>
        <key>age</key>
        <string>12</string>
        <key>gender</key>
        <string>female</string>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>name</key>
        <string>john</string>
        <key>age</key>
        <string>57</string>
        <key>gender</key>
        <string>male</string>
    </dict>
</array>
</plist>
'@
```

How do I convert the xml into Powershell Objects like the following?

**Output**

```
name   age   gender
---    --    -----
bob    35    male
kate   12    female
john   57    male
```

This is what I have tried.

```
$xmldata = [xml]$xml
$xmldict = $xmldata.plist.array.dict
$xmldict
```

This gives the output

```
key                                    string
---                                    ------
{name, age, gender}                    {bob, 35, male}
{name, age, gender}                    {kate, 12, female}
{name, age, gender}                    {john, 57, male}
```

**$xmldict.key**

```
name
age
gender
name
age
gender
name
age
gender
```

Comment: Personally, I'd find a [.Net plist parser](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/406235/A-Simple-PList-Parser-in-Csharp) and use that or otherwise convert it.  Beyond that, this isn't a code writing service.  Try something and come back with your own code when you get stuck.

Answer (score 5):

That's a bit of a weird format where you rely on the order of key/string element pairs.  However, this worked testing against your XML:

```
$xml.plist.array.dict | 
    Foreach {
        $vals = $_.SelectNodes('string'); $_.SelectNodes('key') | 
        Foreach {$ht=@{};$i=0} {$ht[$_.'#text'] = $vals[$i++].'#text'} `
                {new-object psobject -property $ht}
    }
```

This version is a bit more generic in nature - not relying on the `string` element name:

```
$xml.plist.array.dict | 
    Foreach {
        $_.SelectNodes('key') | 
        Foreach {$ht=@{}} {$ht[$_.'#text'] = $_.NextSibling.'#text'} `
                {new-object psobject -property $ht}
    }
```

Comment: Thanks mate. You are a legend. How would you change your code to make it generic so that it would be able to work when the nodes may an integer or a date instead of a string.

Comment: I guess we'll never know

Comment: @Ishan PowerShell will always treat the content as a string. You would need to cast it to an integer when you're expecting one.

Comment: Apple does this all the time.  It works well except when there's an <array> value with multiple <string> values inside it.

Comment: Oh, json is much easier to work with.